# Djangoの絞込検索について

Tags: python, django

Djangoを用いてhttps://www.gumtree.com.auのサイドメニューにある絞込検索を実装したいと思っています。
例としてこのサイトでグローバルメニューにあるJobsをクリックするとサイドメニューに大カテゴリーであるJobsの小カテゴリーが表示されます。また小カテゴリーを選択するとそれに応じたPostが中央にリストで表示されます。
この時点でURLは/BigCategory/、または/SmallCategory/となっています。

また下のようなカテゴリー欄があり

大カテゴリー
｜ー小カテゴリー
｜ー小カテゴリー

この下には

State
｜ーRegion
｜ーRegion

と位置の絞込ができるようになっています。
もしStateを選択すると今選択しているカテゴリー（大カテゴリーか小カテゴリー）に応じて/BigCategory/State/か/SmallCategory/State/でPostが表示されます。
Regionを選択した場合は/BigCategory/Region/か/SmallCategory/Region/となります。

これらのことを実装したいのですが

上記のURLについてまとめると/Category/Location/となりますが、これを自分で考えて実装してみたところ、

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/(?P<loc>[-\w]+)/$', views.loc_index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/$', views.cat_index, name='index'),
]
```

models.py

```
class BigCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SmallCategory(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(BigCategory, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Region(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(SmallCategory)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from .models import BigCategory, SmallCategory, State, Region, Post

def cat_index(request, cat):

    if BigCategory.objects.filter(slug=cat):
        # cat == big
        big_cat = BigCategory.objects.get(slug=cat)
        states = State.objects.all()
        posts = Post.objects.filter(category__parent__slug=cat)
        c = {'big_cat': big_cat, 'states': states, 'posts': posts}

    elif SmallCategory.objects.filter(slug=cat):
        # cat == small
        big_cat = BigCategory.objects.get(children__slug=cat)
        states = State.objects.all()
        posts = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=cat)
        c = {'big_cat': big_cat, 'states': states, 'posts': posts}

    else:
        # raise 404

    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)

def loc_index(request, cat, loc):

    if BigCategory.objects.filter(slug=cat):
        # cat == big
        big_cat = BigCategory.objects.get(slug=cat)
        selected_cat = 'big'

        if State.objects.filter(slug=loc):
            state = State.objects.get(slug=loc)
            posts = Post.objects.filter(category__parent__slug=cat, location__parent__slug=loc)
            c = {'big_cat': big_cat, 'selected_cat': selected_cat, 'state': state, 'posts': posts}

        elif Region.objects.filter(slug=loc):
            state = State.objects.get(children__slug=loc)
            posts = Post.objects.filter(category__parent__slug=cat, location__slug=loc)
            c = {'big_cat': big_cat, 'selected_cat': selected_cat, 'state': state, 'posts': posts}

        else:
            print('no location')

    elif SmallCategory.objects.filter(slug=cat):
        # cat == small
        big_cat = BigCategory.objects.get(children__slug=cat)
        selected_cat = 'small'
        small_cat_for_loc = SmallCategory.objects.get(slug=cat)

        if State.objects.filter(slug=loc):
            state = State.objects.get(slug=loc)
            posts = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=cat, location__parent__slug=loc)
            c = {'big_cat': big_cat, 'small_cat_for_loc': small_cat_for_loc, 'state': state, 'posts': posts}

        elif Region.objects.filter(slug=loc):
            state = State.objects.get(children__slug=loc)
            posts = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=cat, location__slug=loc)
            c = {'big_cat': big_cat, 'small_cat_for_loc': small_cat_for_loc, 'state': state, 'posts': posts}

        else:
            print('no location')

    else:
        # raise 404

    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)
```

このようになりましたが、将来的にカテゴリーや位置だけでなく他のオプションである絞込も実装しようとしたときにいちいち全ての場合分けをしていたらとてもわかりづらく長いコードになってしまいます。

ご教授頂きたいのは、

①URLの場合分けの方法
/BigCategory/SmallCategory/State/Region/とすれば実装は今よりはるかに楽になるのですが、/BigCategory or SmallCategory/State or Region/とすればURLも短くなるのでこのようにしたいです。これを実現するために理想的なviewの書き方をご教授ください。

②上記に記載したコードは私にまだDjangoの知識がなく、がむしゃらに書く殴ったものなのでコード全体、そしてシステム自体の見直しをするにあたっての手ほどきをお願い致します。
例えばカスタムテンプレートタグをこんな風に使えばより楽になる、等

理想は冒頭に記載した参考サイトです。
どうかお助けください。

Answer (score 1):

以下のように考えるとシンプルに実装できそうな気がします。
それぞれのモデルの違いは下記のようになっています。

```
1. BigCategory と SmallCategory は parentを持つか否か
2. State と Region は parentを持つか否か
```

この違いを考慮した上で、それぞれを一つのモデルにまとめると良さそうです。

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # BigCategory と SmallCategory 両方の役割を持つ
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    # State と Region 両方の役割を持つ
    parent = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

今までのデータは以下のようにして取得可能です。

```
# BigCateogry (parentが無い)
Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)

# SmallCategory
Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False)

# State (parentが無い)
Location.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)

# Region
Location.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False)
```

あとはModelのメソッドやQuerySetに工夫をすることで、多数の条件分岐を書かずにviewを実装できそうです。以下に一例を貼ります。(実際に動かすことはしてないのでうまく動かないかもしれません。参考程度にとどめておいてください)

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    @property
    def big_cat(self):
        # parent が nullであれば親カテゴリなので自分自身を返す
        if not self.parent:
            return self
        # そうでなければ親カテゴリ(parent)を返す
        else:
            return self.parent

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    @property
    def state(self):
        # parent が nullであればStateなので自分自身を返す
        if not self.parent:
            return self
        # そうでなければState(parent)を返す
        else:
            return self.parent

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def filter_category(self, category):
        if not category.parent:
            # Big Category であれば、childrenのカテゴリに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(category__in=category.children.all())
        else:
            # Small Category であれば、categoryに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(category=category)

    def filter_location(self, location):
        if not location.parent:
            # State であれば、childrenのlocationに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(location__in=location.children.all())
        else:
            # Region であれば そのlocationに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(location=location)


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = PostQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .models import Category, Location, Post


def cat_index(request, cat):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=cat)
    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', {
        'big_cat': category.big_cat,
        'states': Location.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True).all(),
        'posts': Post.objects.filter_category(category).all()
    })


def loc_index(request, cat, loc):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=cat)
    location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=loc)
    ctx = {
        'big_cat': category.big_cat,
        'state': location.state,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter_category(category).filter_location(location).all()
    }
    if not category.parent:
        ctx.update({'selected_cat': 'big'})
    else:
        ctx.update({'small_cat_for_loc': category})
    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', ctx)
```